# GWCode Categories - No Results

Tags: gwcode-categories

Using GWCode Categories for the first time and it doesn't seem to be working at all. I've installed the plugin (can see it in add-ons / plugins) and running {exp:gwcode_categories}{/exp:gwcode_categories} or any other tag doesn't do anything.

I'm running EE 2.7.3 and 1.8.9 for GWCode Categories.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys. I'm using MSM and needed to enter site_id as a parameter into {exp:gwcode_categories}.

That fixed it :)

Comment: Nice to know it's fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

Could you send your related code to help you with the GWCode Categories problem?

Are you using only ?

```
{exp:gwcode_categories}{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Only using this code will not display nothing. You have to put parameter and code inside to achieve your wish.

```
<ul>
{exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="19" style="linear"}
    <li>{cat_name}</li>
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
</ul>
```

Comment: Adeeb, it is working now?? If you need more help just write which result you want and post your code.